# How do I make my character jump using JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make my character jump using JavaFx. 
When I click <kbd>SPACE</kbd> many times fast, the character fall down rapidly and disappear.
When I click <kbd>SPACE</kbd> many times but slower, the character jumps as it should.

I am not sure what the problem is but I think it has something to do with AnimationTimer and its frames.
Maybe I am using a wrong way to make my character jump, so if it is that, can someone give me the right way? 
I have to use JavaFx.
Avatar: image of my character.
I used gravity and AnimationTimer to make curve like a jump.

```
int gravity = 0;
boolean left, right;
window.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(ePress -> {
           KeyCode keycode = ePress.getCode();
           if(keycode.equals(keycode.D)){
               avatar.setTranslateX(avatar.getTranslateX() + 35);
               right = true;
           }
           if(keycode.equals(keycode.A)){
               avatar.setTranslateX(avatar.getTranslateX() - 35);
               left = true;
           }
           if(keycode.equals(keycode.W)){
               avatar.setTranslateY(avatar.getTranslateY() - 35);
           }
           if(keycode.equals(keycode.S)){
               avatar.setTranslateY(avatar.getTranslateY() + 35);
           }
           if(keycode.equals(keycode.SPACE)){
               double ypreviousPos = avatar.getTranslateY();
               jumpTimer = new AnimationTimer(){
                   @Override
                   public void handle(long now) {
                       avatar.setTranslateY(avatar.getTranslateY() - 10 + gravity);
                       gravity = gravity + 1;
                       if(ypreviousPos == avatar.getTranslateY()){
                             jumpTimer.stop();
                             gravity = 0;
                         }
                       if(right == true ){
                         avatar.setTranslateX(avatar.getTranslateX() + 10);
                         avatar.setTranslateY(avatar.getTranslateY() - 10 + gravity);
                         gravity = gravity + 1;
                         if(ypreviousPos == avatar.getTranslateY()){
                             jumpTimer.stop();
                             gravity = 0;
                         }
                       }  
                        if(left == true ){
                         avatar.setTranslateX(avatar.getTranslateX() - 10);
                         avatar.setTranslateY(avatar.getTranslateY() - 10 + gravity);
                         gravity = gravity + 1;
                         if(ypreviousPos == avatar.getTranslateY()){
                             jumpTimer.stop();
                             gravity = 0;
                         }
                       }
                   }

               };
                   jumpTimer.start();
           }                
        });

        window.getScene().setOnKeyReleased(eRel -> {
             KeyCode keycode = eRel.getCode();
           if(keycode.equals(keycode.D)){
               right = false;
           }
           if(keycode.equals(keycode.A)){
               left = false;
           }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I feel like you could be missing a pair of parenthesis around "10 + gravity"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to avoid starting a new `AnimationTimer` if one is already running: otherwise two (or more) `AnimationTimer`s will be modifying the `translateY` property, and the `gravity` field, simultaneously. As a consequence, you are probably skipping the start position and at least one of the animation timers fails to stop.

Replacing

```
if(keycode.equals(keycode.SPACE))
```

with

```
if(keycode.equals(keycode.SPACE) && gravity==0)
```

should work.

Note also that it's generally a bad idea to test for equality with floating point types. Because of possible rounding errors in floating point arithmetic, you might never get exact equality where you expect it. (In this case, I think it will work, since you are only adding integer values to your `double`; however, you should follow best practice anyway.) You should probably also replace

```
if(ypreviousPos == avatar.getTranslateY())
```

with

```
if(ypreviousPos <= avatar.getTranslateY())
```

Finally, you might consider refactoring this so there is only a single `AnimationTimer`, running constantly, and just arrange for your key handler to change values that cause the timer to make a jump happen.

Comment: thanks for your notes. I found the answer. when I click SPACE many times and the character still didn't finish the jump so the AnimationTimer start again, that's what caused the problem. I added a logical statement to secure that AnimationTimer will not start again until the character finish the jump. that means until the character reach ypreviousPos

Comment: @HusseinAlbirouti Isn't that what I said in this answer? "You need to avoid starting a new `AnimationTimer` if one is already running". Doesn't  `if(keycode.equals(keycode.SPACE) && gravity==0)` achieve exactly that?